# database updates not showing up immediately

Tags: php

i have a php application driven by mysql data. ie. when a user rates on a product .it gets stored in DB and  the page gets refreshed. then also his ratings donot get showed up until cache is cleared. i have put the cache control code also .

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

any tweaks that i have to do for this?

Comment: If you're using a MySQL wrapper, is it caching the data?

Comment: @ N. Lucas - what do you mean by mysql wrapper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table
```